# SQL связь двух пользователей

Tags: sql

Есть таблица с пользователями, требуется добавить функцию добавления в друзья. Возникает два варианта решения:

1. Связывать пользователей одной записью и при запросе искать по двум столбцам.
2. Связывать пользователей двумя записями и при запросе искать по одному столбцу.

В первом случае придется индексировать два столбца, но записей будет меньше. Во втором достаточно проиндексировать один столбец, но и записей будет в два раза больше. Сейчас я использую второй вариант, но появились сомнения в правильности выбора. Подскажите, какой вариант будет работать быстрее и использовать меньше ресурсов.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Он ни разу не исчерпывающий.

Answer (score 4):

Связывайте двумя записями.

- Вставка осуществляется редко, поиск - часто.
- Поиск по индексу будет один - это практически в два раза быстрее при выборке.
- Место на диске под записи - копеечное.

Comment: В MySQL есть возможность сделать индекс для двух столбцов. Есть ли смысл использовать его и какой тип индекса выбрать?